# GREATER THAN ALL

Tags: mysql

Find names of all customers who have loans greater than all loans at Brackendale branch.

Is this ok?

```
Use University;

SELECT customer_name, loan_number
FROM loan NATURAL JOIN customer
HAVING MAX(amount) > ALL (SELECT sum(loan.amount)
FROM loan 
WHERE branch_name = 'Brakendale');
```

Comment: This seems a little odd.  Could you post some sample data, and what you would expect the results to be?  The max(amount) is probably wrong, unless a customer can have multiple loans, in which case, you need a group by customer_name (or ID)

Comment: This feels like a homework question.

Comment: SUGGESTION: enter your schema and query on [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).  Then post a link to it.  This is the SQL equivalent of "posting your code".  PS: I can't imagine that comparing a customer's "max(amount)" with "sum(loan.amount)" for an entire branch could possibly be correct :)

Answer (score 3):

`ALL` is an un-needed keyword - it does nothing as it's the default keyword for a set (the other keyword being `ANY`).

It is more straightforward to leave `ALL` out. But you probably want a group by in there and remove `loan_number`, otherwise each row must be in its own group.

This query seems to make more sense to me:

```
SELECT customer_name, MAX(amount)
FROM loan
NATURAL JOIN customer
GROUP BY customer_name
HAVING MAX(amount) > (
  SELECT sum(loan.amount)
  FROM loan 
  WHERE branch_name = 'Brakendale');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want `MAX` rather than `SUM` in the other direction:

```
SELECT customer_name, loan_number
FROM loan NATURAL JOIN customer
HAVING SUM(amount) > (SELECT max(loan.amount)
                      FROM loan 
                      WHERE branch_name = 'Brakendale'
                     );
```

This would be "All customers who have total total loans greater than the biggest loan in Brakendale".  Your query was more like "All customers who have total loans greater than the sum of all outstanding loans in Brakendale".

You may even want "All customers whose outstanding loans are larger than any customer in Brakendale".  This would be:

```
SELECT customer_name, loan_number
FROM loan NATURAL JOIN customer
HAVING SUM(amount) > (SELECT max(l.CustomerLoans)
                      from (select customerID, sum(l.amount) as CustomerLoans
                            FROM loan l
                            WHERE branch_name = 'Brakendale'
                            group by customerID
                           ) l
                     );
```